# c++ software passing arguments method

Tags: c++, api, node.js, command-line-arguments

I have a problem related to passing arguments to a C++ compiled executable. The program emulate the behaviour of a particular inference engine: the setup of the engine is load at runtime from an XML file, and then I want to call it from command line with different input values.
The characteristic of the input are:

- Every time that I call the program, the input structure is different, because the system itself is different.
- The input is a set of couple {*name, value*}, one for each part of the system.
- I have to separate the configuration XML from the input.
- I call the program from a PHP or Node.js server, since it return a result that I expose to the outside through an API.
- Input value are obtained from an HTTP post request.

By now I have tried these solutions:

1. Pass it from the command line ex: "*./mysoftware input1 value1 input2 value2 ...etc*". A little unconfortable, since I have up to 200 input.
2. Create a file with all the couples *name,value* and then call the program that parse the file and then destroy at the end. This is a bottleneck of performance for my API, because at every call I have to create and destruct a file.

Does anyone know a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: If this is C++ related then don't tag it with C. Those are different languages.

Comment: Why not write a program that takes a file and generates the command line above?

Comment: Any reason why a pipe won't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

3. Pass the values to the program via the standard input stream and read them from `std::cin` inside your C++ program.